# Reconstruction conjecture:Complete graph invariants

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-reconstruction

Suppose we have a complete graph invariant $I$  i.e.  for any two graphs $G$ and $H$  we have $ I(G)=I(H) \iff G \cong H $.
Suppose now that the invariant $I$ is reconstructible from the desk of $G.$ May I  deduce now that the Reconstruction Conjecture  is true?

For example, consider a graph $G$ and let $G_1, G_2,\ldots, G_N$ be the set of  representatives of all  clases  isomorphic subgraphs of $G$. 
 Let  $I(G)=[k_1(G), k_2(G), \ldots, k_N(G)]$ where $k_i(G)$ is number of subgraphs of $G$ which are isomorphic to the subgraph $G_i.$ We have that $I(G)$ is a complete invariant and each  $k_i(G)$ is reconstructible (it follows from Kelly formula)  then  the Reconstruction Conjecture  is true.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is that Kelly's lemma only gives counts for subgraphs with fewer vertices than $G$ and nobody can prove that is a complete invariant.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for stupid questions but  2 points are still uncler for me. 1.  All graphs $G_i$ of course  have fewer  vertices than $G$ so   Kelli's lema works. 2. Does $I(G)$  not complete invariant? There is a counterexample?

Comment: Nobody knows if $I(G)$ is a complete invariant.  Solving that question is basically the same as solving the reconstruction conjecture.